# Use a column as the input parameter to a function and add results to table

Tags: sql

ConvertIPToLong is a function and I'm trying to use the network column from #test1 as the variable @cidrIP.  My results should have the network column and the LowRange and HighRange columns.

```
SELECT * 
from #test1 as t1


Declare @CidrIP varchar(20)
Set @CidrIP = (select [network] from #test1)

Select dbo.[ConvertIPToLong](left(@CidrIP, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIP) - 1)) & (cast(4294967295 as bigint) ^ (Power(2, 32 - Cast(substring(@CidrIP, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIP) + 1, 2) as int)) - 1)) as LowRange
       dbo.[ConvertIPToLong](left(@CidrIP, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIP) - 1)) & (cast(4294967295 as bigint) ^ (Power(2, 32 - Cast(substring(@CidrIP, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIP) + 1, 2) as int)) - 1)) + (Power(2, 32 - Cast(substring(@CidrIP, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIP) + 1, 2) as int)) - 1) as HighRange
```

Comment: To do this you have to create a Sql-String an Execute it dynamically. Which Dbms to you use?

Comment: Microsoft sql server management studio

Comment: Does #test1 only have one row? Otherwise, you have to use a loop.

Comment: #test1 has many rows

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood. I'll give it a try, unchecked though.

Comment: Here is the function if you want to use what I've got:

Comment: ```SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertIPToLong](@IP varchar(15))
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Long bigint
    SET @Long = CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 4)) * 256 * 256 * 256 +
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 3)) * 256 * 256 +
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 2)) * 256 +
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 1))

    RETURN (@Long)
END```

Comment: Does your function have an error, or do I only Need to add the network-column to my answer?

Comment: I can only write unchecked, because I can't verify on Smartphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you,
I'd expect something like this to work:

```
Select dbo.[ConvertIPToLong](left([network], patindex('%/%' , [network]) - 1)) & (cast(4294967295 as bigint) ^ (Power(2, 32 - Cast(substring([network], patindex('%/%' , [network]) + 1, 2) as int)) - 1)) as LowRange
       dbo.[ConvertIPToLong](left([network], patindex('%/%' , [network]) - 1)) & (cast(4294967295 as bigint) ^ (Power(2, 32 - Cast(substring([network], patindex('%/%' , [network]) + 1, 2) as int)) - 1)) + (Power(2, 32 - Cast(substring([network], patindex('%/%' , [network]) + 1, 2) as int)) - 1) as HighRange 
from #test1
```